# Nuxt Axios Returns Error when moving between pages

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am building a nuxt application which I am using axios with.

In my index.vue, I have the following code.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Hero />
    <Homebooks :details="details" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  // USING ASYNC AWAIT
  // async asyncData ({
  //   $axios,
  //   error
  // }) {
  //   try {
  //     const details = await $axios.$get('http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/books')
  //     return {
  //       details
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     error({
  //       statusCode: 503,
  //       mesage: 'Unable to fetch'
  //     })
  //   }
  // }
  // USING ...
  asyncData ({ $axios, error }) {
    return $axios.$get('http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/books').then((response) => {
      return {
        details: response
      }
    }).catch((e) => {
      error({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: 'Unable to fetch data'
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

When I move away from the page to another page. And I come back to it either using the back button or following the link the menu

```
          <nuxt-link to="/" prefetch class="nav-link active">
            Home
          </nuxt-link>
```

It returns the error

> Unable to fetch event
> An error occurred while rendering the page. Check the developer tools console for details.

But when I refresh the page the whole data populate again from the response from the API without error.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Is it saying `Unable to fetch data..` or `Unable to fetch event...` in your console. I think it should be the same string you defined in your catch block?!
Anyway, it seems that your data cannot be fetched after the first time.What does your console say, as indicated in the error message? This would be of great help, because it will tell you more about what is going wrong when fetching your data...

Comment: In the console, it was returning a cors error. After I hosted the api everything seems to work just fine. Is there a way I can prevent cors error locally?

Comment: I have faced so many CORS erros so far, haha. I think here we have a CORS problem because you probably have your local API running with `http` and your hosted API seemed to run the secure protocol `https`. I think it could be a `mixed content` problem. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978207/cross-origin-request-and-mixed-content-only-on-firefox).

Just google mixed content and CORS and you should find some stuff about it, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

In `config/cors.php` use

```
'paths' => ['api/*']
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps or even works at all. Please convince me by explaining your code.